# Use roxygen2 to generate namespace: a small example or template

Tags: r, namespaces, package, roxygen2

Using `roxygen2` to generate `namespace` is completely new to me. Some related questions have been asked and answered multiple times as well as http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html. I still find it difficult for me. I definitely need to read more on this topic. Meanwhile, I just wonder if someone could offer a simple example of code to quickly get me into it first.

I'm not sure the following information will help. I have several functions in the package. The `DESCRIPTION` includes something like:

```
Imports: 
   dplyr, 
   ggplot2,
   survival
```

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried to use `devtools::document()` in your package to get the `namespace` file written, or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: I have tried `devtools::document()`. The NAMESPACE file only has now one line: `# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand`.  How should I fill the space inside the brackets?

Comment: No need to add anything to the brackets. Do you also have a function with roxygen header and a `# @import dplyr` and a `# @export` line? Maybe the document function searches for these lines instead of the description file only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the part that I do not really understand. Where and how to put them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a function within the R folder of you package.

Something like

```
#' Function to plot something
#' 
#' @param my_data a data frame
#' @param x column name for x axis
#' @param y column name for y axis
#' @export
#' @import ggplot2
#' @examples
#' plotSomething(iris, 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width') 
plotSomething <- function(my_data, x, y) {
  ggplot(my_data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
}
```

The keywords `@export` and `@import` will be parsed by `roxygen2` and will update the `NAMESPACE` file after using `devtools::document()`.

Comment: @akrun I wasn't aware of this... 4 month parental leave and now I have to install some updates I guess :-) Thanks for your examples.